# How do I fix a figure getting pushed onto another page. There also appears to be a large buffer area around the image

Tags: graphics, floats

I am new to LaTeX so I apologize. I am adding figures to a report and they keep getting pushed to the next page. There is also a large border around the image that creates a gap between the image and caption.

```
  \textbf{Part Two}
    Use MATLAB to plot the unit-step response of the system model
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{./Images/step2.pdf}
    \caption{Step Response of System}
    \label{fig:step2}
    \end{figure}
```

The image attached is what is compiling[image: pdf output]

Comment: check your image I suspect that it is a full page pdf and the image is just a small part of it so you are adding the space. latex doesn't add that much space before the caption. as for rmoving: that is the only purpose of the `figure` environment but if your figure is over-large and you mark it with `[h]`so prevent it being placed at the top or bottom of the page it is quite likely to float to the end of the document.

Comment: have a try with tag [h!] instead of [h], this sometimes helps.

Comment: Try putting an \fbox around your image to see how big it really is.